# Put text in column before each first unique record

Tags: excel, if-statement, text, excel-formula, unique

I have a worksheet with 4 columns:

```
Column A: Identifier
Column D: Date of Event
Column H: Yet empty
Column I: Analyst Masked Codes
```

A picture to make it more clear:

[image: http://static.afbeeldinguploaden.nl/1406/70058/qW6T.PNG]

I have identifiers (they go from EM1 till EM161). I want to have the word `initiation` placed before every first entry of an unique `Analyst Masked Codes`. So in this case row 1, 3, 5 etc. However, I can not just use advanced filter and unique records because sometimes the same `Analyst Masked Codes` occurs for more than one identifier, and I want the first record for each observation (row) for each identifier.

I hope there is some trick or coding that can solve my problem?

Comment: Well, that was just very stupid from me. Indeed I mean 1,3,6. As observation I mean each row, which is a specific event on that particular date. So I want to filter in some way (or use a macro) that I get the first entry of each unique observation analyst code, grouped for identifiers.

Comment: http://static.afbeeldinguploaden.nl/1406/70061/0DatO.PNG. Here I tried to make it more clear.. I really hope someone can help me out, because otherwise I have to look through 640.000 observations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Columnl is in H1 and that your data is sorted, try:

```
=IF(I1=I2,"","initiation")
```

in H2 and copy down.

Comment: Woow! That I didn't come up with that.. Thank you so freaking much! You saved my sleeping schedule for the upcoming week